# Use Invoke-SQLCmd and return number of rows deleted/affected

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a very simple powershell command, where $query is just "delete from mytable"

```
Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseserver -Username $databaseuser -Password $databasepassword -Database $databasename -Query $query| Out-File -filePath $output
```

However, this does NOT output the number of rows affected?

The equivalent in SQLCMD **does** output the no rows affected:

```
& sqlcmd -S . -U $databaseuser -P $databasepassword -Q $query    -o $output
```

Is there any way to get `Invoke-sqlcmd` to return the number of rows?

Comment: Why don't you write your own Invoke-SqlCmd that would call .NET instead? Should be able to use [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Comment: Or just continue to use sqlcmd.exe, I think you'll find other features in sqlcmd.exe missing from invoke-sqlcmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the ROWCOUNT function feature in SQL immediately after your query to do the following:

```
Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

Using your PowerShell as an example:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM MyTable; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS DeletedRows"
$Results = Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseserver -Username $databaseuser -Password $databasepassword -Database $databasename -Query $query| Out-File -filePath $output
Write-Host "Total rows deleted: $($Results.DeletedRows)"
```

More information on ROWCOUNT @ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316(v=sql.90).aspx

In addition, you could take a row count before the deletion of records and do another row count after deletion then do the difference. This will only work on inserted/deleted records and will not work on for records that are updated.

```
SELECT COUNT( my_table.my_col ) AS row_count
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that newer versions of `Invoke-Sqlcmd` support a `-Statistics` flag which provides some of this information. It does bundle some stuff under `IDUCount` rather than providing a distinct `DeletedCount` but it's better than nothing.

The following example code belongs to Microsoft and can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-15-capture-connection-statistics-via-statisticsvariable-parameter). I'm providing it here to avoid a link only answer.

```
Import-Module SQLServer
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -StatisticsVariable stats `
              -Query 'CREATE TABLE #Table (ID int); INSERT INTO #Table VALUES(1), (2); INSERT INTO #Table VALUES(3); SELECT * FROM #Table'

Write-Host "Number of rows affected......: $($stats.IduRows)"
Write-Host "Number of insert statements..: $($stats.IduCount)"
Write-Host "Number of select statements..: $($stats.SelectCount)"
Write-Host "Total execution time.........: $($stats.ExecutionTime)ms"

# When you run the code fragment above, is going to be something like this:  
#
# Number of rows affected......: 3
# Number of insert statements..: 2
# Number of select statements..: 1
# Total execution time.........: 5ms
```